# REFrostedViewController exception when use two mapView

Tags: ios

I am using REFrostedViewController.

When I use two uiViewController with mapView, I have got error when I switch beetwen one uiViewController and second uiViewController.

My error is:

```
[__NSCFData backdropView:willChangeToGraphicsQuality:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14e95230
2014-06-12 15:24:29.411 App[4858:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFData backdropView:willChangeToGraphicsQuality:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14e95230'
```

Comment: Are you using cocoapods for REFrostedViewController?

Comment: I don't use cocoapods